# Laravel blade @yield and @section

Tags: php, laravel, templates, layout, laravel-blade

on my main.blade.php

```
<div class="container">
     @yield('content')
</div>
```

on my home.blade.php

```
@extends('main')

    @section('content')
    <div class="row">
        <h1>this content should show on my main</h1>
    </div>
    @endsection
```

what could be wrong it's not displaying the content on my @section i have no errors but it's not working by the way I'm using Laravel 5.4

Comment: where is the main php located? and where is the home blade located?

Comment: @exprator they are both located at resources and inside view folder

Comment: means both are in the same directory right? like main.php,home.php?

Comment: try using `@stop` instead of `@endsection`

Comment: @Exprator yes they are

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your main.blade.php and home.blade.php lies in 
`resource/views/`

If they lie in different directory use " . " to specify directory

For example, if main.blade.php is in `resource/views/layouts` then it would be something like this `@extends('layouts.main')`

Comment: yes they are both on the resources inside view folder

Comment: what's the output you get

Comment: nothing the content that was supposed to be displayed on the main.blade.php is not included when i check the page source

Answer (score -1):

I think you need to update your code for `main.blade.ph`p like:

```
<div class="container">
     @yield('content')
</div>
```

To

```
<section class="content">
     @yield('content')
</section>
```

Hope this work for you

Comment: I am surprised. How just changing `div` to `section` could have solved the problem?

Comment: @Bhavik Shah nah it did not